# Closed form of matrix $ (I-(1- α)P)^{-1}$

Tags: matrix-equations, block-matrices

I am having difficulties in proving the closed form of matrix $(I-(1- α)P)^{-1}$ into the equation below. I got this equation from a research paper and i failed to understand how they got there.

If $I$ is an $m × m$ identity matrix. According to matrix

[image]

they said a closed form of $(I-(1- α)P)^{-1}$ is equals to below, but I failed to understand the process of getting here

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you..

Comment: Are we to assume that $P$ is a projector? Or that the $\pi$ are? $$(I+aP)(I+bP)=I+(a+b+ab)P$$ if $P$ is a projector, so $I+bP=(I+aP)^{-1}$ if $b=-\frac{a}{1+a}$.

Comment: Also, look up Morrison-Sherman-Woodbury, they deal with inverses and determinants of block matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a scalar, $b$ a row and $c$ a column vector, $D$ an invertible matrices, all of compatible dimensions to form a block matrix. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&D
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-D^{-1}c&I
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a-bD^{-1}c&b\\0&D
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&bD^{-1}\\
0&I
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
a-bD^{-1}c&0\\0&D
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&D
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-D^{-1}c&I
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
(a-bD^{-1}c)^{-1}&0\\0&D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-bD^{-1}\\
0&I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so on...